# Does vim support unicode?

Tags: vim, locale, gvim, system-language

I recently changed my system language to Tamil (a language used in India) from English. While I was enjoying Ubuntu in Tamil, my favorite editor vim has run into an issue because of the system language change, it seems.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `:set encoding=utf-8`

Answer (score 1):

I would try running this in from the vim terminal while the offending file is opening

```
:set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,sjis
```

and if that doesn't work, you should be able to find what you need here [Vim User Manual Language Encoding](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_45.html)

What happens if you run vim from the terminal and not gvim?

Comment: 1) I tried setting that, it didnt help. Moreover, I wasnt even able to confirm the result of that command, since I couldnt read anything. 
2) I tried to open vim from the terminal and it works like a charm. This is the output of `:langauge`
`Current language: "LC_CTYPE=ta_IN.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=ta_IN.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=ta_IN.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=ta_IN.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=ta_IN.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=ta_IN.UTF-8;LC_NAME=ta_I
N.UTF-8;LC_ADDRESS=ta_IN.UTF-8;LC_TELEPHONE=ta_IN.UTF-8;LC_MEASUREMENT=ta_IN.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=ta_IN.UTF-8"`
3) gvim didnot work both from command line and direct invocation

Comment: @thefourtheye maybe your gvim needs to be re-installed.  It doesn't seem to be a problem with Vim just Gvim.